# How do I create my own mulch?

Tags: mulch

[image]I have a pile of small wood chips from felled trees.
I want to create black mulch.
Can I do it and how?

Comment: Please note that the “no answers I’m comments” rule is still valid. If you are unsure of what you are suggesting, I recommend you re-read [answer] and then decide whether it’s an answer or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can buy mulch dyes in a variety of colors. A simple google search will reveal many sources. I have no idea what's in them, but one said "environmentally safe", whatever that may mean.

Comment: sprayed my mulch with a product like you suggested and it looks great.  If it's mulch it's perfect; doesn't work so well on twigs or areas with sparse mulch.  Think it is a great idea to refresh every other year to save money.

Comment: If you think about it, stop by again next year and update us on how it holds up over time.

Comment: I will.  You can see the difference.  My thinking is to re-mulch every OTHER year and color the next.  It doesn't color the dirt so well and the mulch gets kicked around.  But if it saves me $8K/yr it's worth it.